# Vuex mapState not working in Vue2

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I'm using `mapState` to map the data in my component, but it's not working:

```
computed: mapState({
  results: function (state) {
    // here not work 
    console.log('map', state.cardData);
    return state.cardData;
  },
  isloadingComplete: function (state) {
    return state.isloadingComplete;
  },
  busy: function (state) {
    return state.busy;
  }
```

[source code](https://github.com/TIGERB/easy-vue/blob/feature/webpack2/src/components/card.vue)

Comment: If you remove `console.log`, does it works?